# Selenium webdriver element.click() not functioning in expected manner (chrome, mocha)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm testing a log in feature for a website, and even though I can properly locate the Login button, `.click()` does not seem to be working the way I expect it to.

First, the relevant test js code:

```
driver.sleep(1000)
driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys(fakeEmail);
driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys(fakePassword);
driver.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).isEnabled()
.then(function(isEnabled) {
    console.log(isEnabled) // prints true
    var el = driver.findElement(By.name('password'));
    el.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER); //method 1
})
//note: these xpaths are correct. I am able to get inner text, for example
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER); //method 2
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click(); //method 3
```

Next, here is the code in the login button html:

`<button type="submit" ng-disabled="attempt_Error" ng-class="{'disabled': (!(usr.email &amp;&amp; usr.password) || attempt_Error)}" ng-if="!reset_Hash &amp;&amp; !forgotMode" class="btn btn-prim ng-scope" style=""> Log in</button>`

Expected behavior (this works manually):

1. On mouseover, button changes to color1.
2. On click, button changes to color2.
3. Assuming correct email and password, on release, go to homepage.

What I see upon execution:

1. Button changes to color2.
2. Nothing happens.
3. The window stays open, but if I try to click the button manually, nothing happens.

I have labeled Methods 1-3 in my js code, and none of them give the expected behavior. I have tried them all separately and in conjunction. I have already tried just trying to go to the homepage after doing this, but I am indeed not logged in.

My question is: why isn't `element.click()` acting the way I want it to act?

Edit: I know that login(form) is being called because I have a console log. Here is something interesting though: there is a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" error in the console! If I keep clicking the button afterwards, I get `angular.js:8632 POST http://localhost:9000/api/session 403 (Forbidden)`. That error is not there if I do this manually! Any idea why?

Versions:

```
"chai": "^4.1.0",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"chromedriver": "^2.31.0",
"mocha": "^3.4.2",
"selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0",
```

Comment: You do both sendKeys AND click to the same element?

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

Comment: I tried both, and neither worked. I read that `sendKeys(ENTER)` could be used to also simulate a click. But yeah, none of those methods work, and I tried them all separately.

Comment: Could you post the html of the page being tested? It sounds like you are finding the element successfully, and clicking it, if it changes to color2. You just aren't being redirected?

Comment: Not only am I not getting redirected, the login function isn't even happening. If it *did* log me in, then even if I wasn't redirected, just refreshing the page would take me to the home screen.

Here is the surrounding form html: `<form name="form" ng-submit="forgotMode?forgotPass(form):(resetHash?resetPass(form):login(form))" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">`

Comment: What happens when you manually login by typing the password and immediately hitting enter, with the text cursor still in the form?

Comment: I know that `login(form)` is being called because I have a console `log`. Here is something interesting though: there is a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" error in the log! That error is not there if I do this manually! Any idea why?

Comment: Manually hitting enter after typing the password, while still in the password field, works fine. I'll be adding in the 403 error stuff in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very ugly solution... given that the 403 errors were the main problem, I just put

```
driver.get('http://localhost:9000');
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

in the beginning of the test. So it first navigates to localhost:9000; then it navigates there again. Then it refreshes. And that solves the problem.

I'm not sure why though, but there it is.